# Image tooltip not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

I am trying to display an Image as a tool tip when hovered onto an image. I have read various posts on Stack Overflow and have tried but still it is not working. I am learning jQuery and would like some help to show me what aspect of tooltip am I missing?

Here is the code I am using so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".panel").tooltip({
        delay: 0,
        showURL: false,
        track: true,
        bodyHandler: function () {
            return '<img src="images/b_clicktozoom.jpg" alt="Click to Zoom" width="88px" height="20px"/>';
        }
    });
});
```

The html is following:

```
 <div class="belt">
     <div class="panel" style="float: none; position: absolute; left: 2643px;">
         <img width="879" height="510" border="0" usemap="#xyz.jpg"alt="Writing on the Wall" src="xxx.jpg">
     </div>
 </div>
```

Please let me know your thoughts on this

Thanks

Comment: That's all well and good, but what's your problem? What isn't working? Have you had a look at your browser's error console?

Comment: are you including the reference to tooltip script file? What is the error you get? make sure you include the scripts in correct order

Comment: have you seen this example? http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tooltip/index.htm

Comment: @JamWaffles : yeah I did look at the error console and it says nothing  about the error. what exactly is the situation is that I have a carousel of images and I want to show the tooltip on them. On the first image when I hover , it shows me the second image in a 80x20 frame on top

Comment: @tq : yeah I did see the example before I did try to do it myself. The  '<img>' tag has no 'title' in it , so I didnt use it , but is there a way I can use '$("#demo img["source of image i want"]").tooltip();'  ??

Answer (score 0):

Are you including the jQuery tooltip external JS file in your page? tooltip() will not work without the tooltip plugin included on your page. You can download it from http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/

Comment: Might want to look at using a different tooltip plugin. I'm not sure if that one is supported any longer. Looks like it hasn't been updated in years. Here is a link that has several other tooltip plugins: 
http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/stylish-jquery-tooltip-plugins-webdesign/

Answer (score 0):

Go to the following URL

http://flowplayer.org/tools/tooltip/index.html

and include it as the following in the script tag:

src="http://cdn.jquerytools.org/1.2.6/full/jquery.tools.min.js"

and then call it on the html tag element e.g., $("label").tooltip();

Comment: thanks ! yeah this did help me a little but the thing is I still can't see my image on the tooltip.it is now just showing me the default tooltip. the code is as follows `$(document).ready(function(){ 
  $(".panel").tooltip({ 
        delay: 0, 
        showURL: false, 
        track : true,
        bodyHandler:function() { 
     return '<img src="images/b_clicktozoom.jpg" alt="Click to                  Zoom" width="88px" height="20px"/>'; //b_clicktozoom.jpg  
    } 
 });
  
}); $.event.props.splice($.event.props.indexOf("layerY"),1);
 $.event.props.splice($.event.props.indexOf("layerX"),1); `